# Folder access permissions on a separate partition

Tags: mac, permissions, osx-lion

I'm having trouble accessing my data on my other dual-boot partition that's running Snow Leopard.  I'm trying to access the `Library` folder from my Lion partition, but I'm having permission issues.  This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

How might I enable access to this folder (from my SL partition) so that I can access it in Lion without messing up the permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Library folder and add a new permission and select yourself and give yourself read/write.

[image]

You will then be able to access the folder :
[image]

Comment: That doesn't work. Adding permissions on the SL volume's folder in Lion did not allow me to access it.

Comment: Let me get this straight first, You are trying to access a HD that has SL installed via another HD which has Lion installed.

Comment: That is correct.  However, I can access the drive up until I hit the Library folder in the user directory.  That is where I get the permission snag.

Comment: That is normal behavior.
I've updated my post, please check it out.

Do you anything protecting the user's home folder in the SL OS ?

Comment: Whoops.  After unchecking the "ignore permissions" and restarting (after installing a 10.7.2 delta update) it looks like the issue resolved itself.  Maybe it just wasn't detecting the changes on the permissions.  Thanks for the help! ;)